# Экран настроек приложения, оптимальный способ реализации

Tags: android

В разработке собственного приложения столкнулся с вопросом реализации экрана настроек приложения. Мне сложно выбрать оптимальный способ его реализации. Постараюсь описать способы между которыми выбираю. Помогите выбрать.

Экран с настройками:[image: Скрин]

**1-й способ:** Реализация через панель. В домашнем (главном) экране сделать кнопку "НАСТРОЙКИ", которой назначить слушатель с методом **setVisibility(...)**.То есть, панель скрыта (GONE) по-умолчанию в главном экране, по клику на "НАСТРОЙКИ" она становиться видимой (VISIBLE). 
**Смущает:** Если сделать фон панели с настройками прозрачной или полупрозрачной прокликаваются кнопки ПОД панелью, т.е. домашнего экрана. И второе, если в эту панель поместить кнопку "НАЗАД" для закрытия (GONE) этой панели, то кнопка попросту не работает.

**2-й способ:** Создание новой Empty Activity. Тут более проще. Создать макет XML + class и реализовать через Intent.
**Смущает:** Пока не сталкивался с сохранением чего либо в приложениях, но в процессе познания данного вопроса. Кажется, что созданный класс будет пустовать, ведь можно прописать код для настроек, например, в классе домашнего экрана - если я ошибаюсь, прошу, поправьте меня.

**3-й способ:** Создать Settings Activity. Аналогично 2-му способу, но об этой активити мне ничего не известно, да и в сети ничего не нашел - гугл рекомендует использовать Preference. **Смущает:** Все!

ПС: Я новичок, учусь сам, преимущественно книгами. Поэтому буду признателен если ответ будет простыми словами. Спасибо. (если позволите буду уточнять ответ в комментариях).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настройки через `Preference`, рекомендуемые гуглом - боль и страдания. Проще сделать вручную.

Вручную можно сделать по разному. Активити то будет отдельная или нет - дело вкуса. Можно и так и так - оба способа нормальны. Но, если делать не отдельной активити, то делать надо во фрагменте - для разделения логики. Вписывать код настроек вьюхой в к-л другой экран - плохая идея.

Лично я делаю иногда `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, в котором и отображаю настройки. Так есть полный контроль над внешним видом + не надо отдельную активити делать. Но можно и просто во фрагменте. Если с ними не сталкивались ещё - то отдельная активити - ваш вариант.

Собственно хранить настройки надо в `SharedPreferences` - это стандартный способ. Обычно пишут класс-синглтон в коем экземпляр `SharedPreferences` используется и в него что-то пишется и читается отдельными методами. Собственно интерфейс экрана настроек эти методы и дёргает и из них свойства вьюхам проставляет (числа, параметры там всякие etc)

Comment: Можно немного вопросов сразу)? То есть, как я понял, 2-й способ мне как новичку - это оптимальное решение. 1-й - не рекомендуете совсем. - Верно? 3-й - как я только что выяснил, это автосоздание ряда макетов, заполненного  класса и строковых ресурсов. Разобраться пока не смог. Откатил. 
 Вы правы, с фрагментами еще не сталкивался. Боюсь их до жути.  Можете очень коротко сказать в чем суть BottomSheetDialogFragment?
Спасибо за SharedPreferences. Не знал. Догадывался что сохранять данные нужно в отдельном файле, но не знал где и как. Да и в целом спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Не могу согласится про "боль и страдания", да немного мудрено, зато получаем автосохранение в SharedPreferences, колбэки на изменение значений и готовый UI. Самому все это писать больнее и страдальнее, все эти *"пишут класс-синглтон .."* естественно МСЛМ и от количества настроек зависит, как на скриншоте для двух параметров вполне проще и самому запилить, но не в общем случае, особенно с вложенностью.

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов в первую очередь у вас не должно быть такой "отмазки", как *"мне как новичку"* - не нужно городить костыли под этим предлогом, правильно понемногу осваивать принятые и отработанные практики, а правильный способ это все же 3-вариант, который имеет определенные и существенные преимущества перед первыми двумя, особенно в относительно сложной структуре настроек.

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо за ответ. Думаю, вне рамках этой работы разобраться с 3-м способом.